# How can i change Custom Amount text in Square Connect API. Point of Sale app?

Tags: ios, square-connect, point-of-sale

I have an issue with point-of-sale-api-ios, I am unable to change the text on print, it's showing **Custom Amount** on the transaction receipt:

[image: Receipt image]

I am able to send notes etc and finishing the Transaction.

How can I change the "Custom Amount" Text to some other text?

Comment: This SDK? https://github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS I don't see the text "Custom Amount" in there.

Comment: This seems API-specific question.
You could check out the slack community and ask them directly - https://buildwithsquare.slack.com/join/shared_invite/enQtMzM2NjYwODYzMDA5LTI2NWFlZGZiMzYwYTJlZGZjYmNmMzc1MThjZGU4NTQ3NzQ0MDE0MGEwOWYzZGViZDc1Yzk3MzVjODEyNmIwYzY?ref=docsfooter

Comment: here is the link for my transaction receipt screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDa58.png in that its showing custom amount i want to change to my text.

Comment: Are you manually entering an amount, rather than choosing an item? If you choose an item, it should show the item's name instead of "Custom Amount".

Comment: Thank you sjosey, i am manually sending amount from my app to Point of sale app.